# framework not found flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle flutter

Tags: flutter

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done. 58.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
ld: framework not found flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description

Comment: Please specify what are trying to do. It is unclear in the first sentence what is program output and what is description of the problem. Also, format your output preserving whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

dependencies:
flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle: ^1.0.8

try to use this and pod install again

Comment: still I get same error i am not use this dependency in my app and this error happen when i was update to v1.20

Comment: compileSDKVersion to 29 instead of 28.